# How to loop a vimeo video?

Tags: loops, video, vimeo

I'm trying to add a loop functionality to my vimeo video but is not working. Do you know if it's not supported on Chrome (Mac) or is there a way to fix it?

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/112412666#t=0s?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1" width="700" height="467" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of research I found out that the problem was the "#t=0s" after the video ID, so the code should looks like this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="700" height="467" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/112412666?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;autopause=0&amp;color=fdea2e"></iframe>
```